# Loading custom ICC profile into InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, color-profile

I have been going around in circles with colour profiles for a while now and I'm not getting anywhere.

I am working between Photoshop and InDesign to prepare a presentation of a hand-drawn colour sketch which has been inverted in Photoshop to be on a black background. In Photoshop, I apply a custom ICC profile to a scanned image. Our head office has developed this profile and it has been checked in their office against the profile they use there (different scanner). They are happy with the unity of results between the two profiles for output files.

I am trying to convince head office that we should be working with InDesign instead of Photoshop for multi-page presentations and it is therefore important that any changes applied in Photoshop come across to InDesign too. At the moment, the Photoshop file (either as a PSD or as a PDF or JPG conversion) looks very different in Indesign. The blacks are grey. A JPG generated from Photoshop directly is attached [image: attached] along with 2 JPGs generated from INDD using proPhoto [image: proPhoto] and sRGB [image: sRGB].

I cannot see how to load this same ICC profile (RGB) into my InDesign template. In Colour Settings I get an error message of "Some parameters in the colour settings file could not be used. Default values will be used instead". How can I load the ICC profile?

Using a proPhoto profile is not bad, but the blues are far too bright. If this is the solution, I would need to create a Photoshop action or series of actions to colour manage the source document. I'd rather not.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In Windows: copy profile into the folder:

```
Windows\System32\spool\drivers\color
```

In Mac OS, copy profile into the folder:

```
/Library/ColorSync/Profiles
```

Or

```
/Users/{username}/Library/ColorSync/Profiles
```

Then restart Adobe applications.

Comment: I checked this but it is already there. It is not showing up in the list of options available for RBG profiles, and when I select load, I receive an error message of "Some parameters in the colour settings file could not be used. Default values will be used instead".

Comment: @KimbaF can you share your profile somehow (dropbox, or whatever)? I'll try to have a look. Do you have PC or Mac?

Comment: sure thing. Link here. I'm using a PC. Thanks! https://www.dropbox.com/s/puf4op32vd9lw62/Samsung_CLX-9250_Scanner.icc?dl=0